# If every async has an await and every await is applied to an async, then where and how does this end?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have just been introduced to this concept, so apologies if the answer is trivial.

I understand that `async` is just a flag that says there is an `await` inside the method and control will return to the caller while the async method is doing its work. My understanding is that this is useful assuming somewhere in the call stack an async method is not awaited, not immediately at least (i.e. some other work is done while the async method is executing).

However, `await` seems to be only applied to `async` methods, which in turn must have `await`s inside. This creates an endless chain of calls. It must end somewhere, with an await being applied to a non-async method. But where?

Comment: You can't await a non-async method, you can however wait for the async method to finish it's work by accessing the Result  property of a Task. You can use that to "cut off" then async chain, or you can just have your whole chain be async.

Comment: @TamásSzabó - yes you can. You can `await` any method that returns an *awaitable* object. `Task` happens to be the most common awaitable. But even there, there's no requirement that the `Task` returning method be `async`. Despite it's appearance as being part of the method signature, it is in fact entirely an *implementation* detail of the method you're calling.

Comment: Guess I was in the wrong. Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, await seems to be only applied to async methods, which in turn must have awaits inside.

Technically, `await` is not applied to methods. What happens is the method is called and returns something (e.g., a `Task`), and then the `await` is applied *to that task*.

So, the misunderstanding is here: `await` is applied to awaitables (e.g., tasks), not methods.

> It must end somewhere, with an await being applied to a non-async method.

Yup. Any method can return a `Task` (or any awaitable), whether it's `async` or not. A method *can* use `async` to construct its task (and most of the methods *we* write do it this way), but it can also build one directly. Usually, low-level asynchronous methods use `TaskFactory.FromAsync` or `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to create their task that they return.

Answer (score -1):

It ends up on the highest layer you are using and which you don't want to block. Let's say you have an Winforms Application. All Methods here will end up in some event and this would be the end of your async chain.

For example:

```
private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
   await DbClass.GetSomeItemsFromDbAsync();
}

public partial class MyForm : Form
{
   private async void btButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      await DoSomethingAsync();
   }
}
```

If you can see in the example, we have one Method which is async. This method is called in the Click-Event of a Button. So the Event-Listener is marked as async but can't be called from anything else. Here you leave your chain and the endpoint is reached. The Form won't block and thats what we want to achieve.

If you think on GUI all Methods will end up in events, because the whole Program is Event-Driven. In Console App the Endpoint would be the Main-Method. There you don't change the return type from void to Task and this will stop your async chain, because void can't be awaited.

I hope this helps you to understand the chain.

Comment: is it normal to use `async void` in Windows Forms?

Comment: @mukh1n To use it on the Event-Listener: Yes because this is your endpoint. Use it in "normal" methods should be avoided, because you can't await that later on.

Comment: I was actually asking about the lowest level (see Stephen's answer). But yours is a good point too: somebody at a high level has to not `await` it, at least not immediately, for the whole thing to be meaningful.